# To change panel size according to the screen size

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, responsive

On my website, I have a panel on the right side (Image 1) that slides in and out on click of a button. I have set the dimensions of the panel such that it covers the entire height of the screen.[image]

This is the CSS that I use for this panel-

```
slide-in-panel-component{ display:none; position: fixed;top: -10px; margin-right: 20px; height: 100vh; width:600px; right: -600px; background-color: #fff3e2;z-index:9999999}
```

As I change the screen size (or on a smaller screen), I want the panel to show in it's entirety, but adjusted to the size of the screen i.e. its height should change according to the height of the screen.
Currently, as in Image 2, if I decrease the screen size, it goes over the panel and hides certain components of the panel.[image]

I tried using position:fixed, setting min-height but could not get the desired result.

Comment: Change `width:600px;` to some percentage say `width:30%;`

Comment: yes, as Pavan said, you have to use responsive values, rather than fixed values.

Comment: I had tried that (using width: 50%;) but that did not fix it.

Comment: What about position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the position fixed and top, right, bottom properties. Like so:

```css
.panel {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it still doesn't work for me as I want it to. Do you think the elements inside the panel could be causing this to happen? Or should just changing the css of the outer-most class solve this?

Comment: When I decrease/adjust the screen size from the bottom, as in Image 2, certain parts of the panel get hidden(still); the panel should have sized down with the size of the screen, to show itself entirely.

Comment: That is probably because you are not positioning those parts inside the panel correctly. The panel itself sticks and resizes to the screen, but you still need to make sure if you have a sticky bar inside that panel to position it relatively, not absolutely.

Comment: The panel sticks alright but as I decrease the screen size it does not resize (I'm using position: fixed; though) and ends up being clipped by the screen (as in the second screenshot), so some of the info. inside it still gets hidden